# Equivalente ao inglês «gasp» — inspirar rápida e audivelmente devido a surpresa ou choque

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

Tenho a certeza que toda a gente já fez e ouviu isto: devido a uma surpresa, choque ou dor súbita, a pessoa inspira rapidamente de boca aberta, produzindo um ahhh claramente audível, ficando depois momentaneamente de boca aberta e respiração cortada. Em inglês diz-se *gasp* [(ver Merriam-Webster, primeira das *Simple Definition* e *Full definition 1*)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gasp)

Como um som vale por mil palavras, podem [ouvir aqui (duas primeiras gravações, *male gasping* e *woman gasping in shock*)](http://www.soundsnap.com/tags/gasping).

Em filmes já vi traduzir por *suspiro* ou *suspirar*, e o Google translator concorda. Mas está errado: o suspiro ([ver aqui](http://www.aulete.com.br/suspiro) e [ouvir aqui](http://www.soundsnap.com/tags/sigh)) é quase o inverso do *gasp*. O [Google translator](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=english%20portuguese%20dictionary) indica também [*arquejar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/arfar) e [*arfar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/arfar), mas isto corresponde a outros significados de *gasp*.

As expressões portuguesas relacionadas que conheço descrevem o que acontece depois do *gasp*: *ficar de boca aberta* e *ficar de respiração cortada*. Mas o que eu quero é um verbo e um substantivo que correspondam mesmo a *gasp*, ao inspirar com o ahhh audível.

Tenho quase a certeza que não existe com este significado uma palavra corrente de uso generalizado. Mas sendo o *gasp* um ato tão comum, será que não existe alguma palavra, seja um termo técnico ou um regionalismo? Ou mesmo uma palavra que alguém usasse lá em casa?

Seguindo a prática recomendada nos *single-word-requests* do ELU, deixo aqui duas frases com espaço em branco para preencher com o verbo e substantivo equivalentes a *gasp*.

> Ela _______ quando se deu conta que já estava uma hora atrasada para a reunião.
>
> Ouviu-se um/uma _________ coletivo/a quando inesperadamente ele anunciou que a empresa ia encerrar.

Uma descrição alternativa aos exemplos acima seria, sem referência ao som do *gasp*, *cortou-se-lhe a respiração quando se deu conta...* e *cortou-se-lhes a respiração quando ele lhes anunciou...*. Mas fico à espera de termos mais exatos.

Comment: Eu usaria nessas frases o verbo suspirar mesmo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não é que um *suspiro*  de desânimo fosse completamente descabido nestas frases, mas *suspiro* é praticamente o contrário do que eu pretendo, que é um *gasp* de choque: a expiração é que é audível [(vê Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/suspiro) e ouve [aqui](http://www.soundsnap.com/tags/sigh).

Comment: Jacinto eu entendi o que tu queres, e mesmo assim era o que eu utilizaria, *suspiro*: *"Ela suspirou quando se deu conta que já estava uma hora atrasada para a reunião."* e *"Ouviu-se um suspiro coletivo quando inesperadamente ele anunciou que a empresa ia encerrar."*

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas então quem te houve não compreende o que realmente aconteceu. No segundo exemplo, se me falassem em *suspiro*, eu imaginaria o pessoal desanimado; se me falassem em *gasp*, eu imaginaria choque. Se necessário temo que inventar. Que tal *gaspar*: eu gaspo, tu gaspas, ele gaspa...

Comment: Jacinto eu compreendo o *suspiro* de forma diferente consoante o contexto e a entoação da frase. Na escrita temos de ser mais específicos, *e ela suspirou de alivio*, por exemplo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Os suspiros são geralmente de tédio, impaciência, desejo, etc., não tanto de surpresa ou choque, até porque são mais demorados.

Comment: @Artefacto Ou saudade, tristeza, desânimo (estes modelados em *ai*), alívio. São mais demorados por serem produzidos por expiração gradual, enquanto o *gasp* é súbito por ser produzido por interrupção da inspiração.

Comment: Aliás, @JorgeB., complementando o que diz o Artefacto, eu diria que nos suspiros expiramos mas nos «gasp» inspiramos; um é mais um ato lento e o outro mais um ato repentino. (Agora sim, sem trocar as exalações com as inalações... obrigado Jacinto!)

Comment: Eu não concordo com essas vossas apreciações sobre suspirar. Muito do que eu ouvi nos exemplos do Jacinto é suspiro.

Comment: Para esse caso usa-se "engoliu seco"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca vira esta palavra, mas de um [dicionário de inglês-espanhol](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-spanish/gasp) cheguei a [*boquear*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5s5w6AR), que não parece ser muito relevante («abrir la boca; estar expirando»), mas cuja correspondente em português [***boquear***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/boquear) é assim definida no Priberam:

> 1. Abrir a boca para respirar sofregamente (como o asmático).
> 2. [Figurado] Agonizar.

Portanto parece não ter tanto a ideia de *ofegar*, *arquejar* e *arfar*, que estão mais associados a cansaço e a movimentos de respiração amplos. A definição parece estar de acordo com [esta passagem](https://books.google.nl/books?id=j_6uCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT19&dq=%22boquear%22%20sempre&pg=PT19#v=onepage&q=%22boquear%22%20sempre&f=false):

> Baixou do vagão-dormitório e sentiu que seus pulmões se abriam e o ar entrava. Deixou de boquear como um bagre (essa era a sua comparação), a pedra que o esmagava bem no meio do peito se dissolveu e ele começou a respirar.

Este é sem dúvida um significado que *gasp* pode ter ([1 do OED para *gasp* como verbo<sup>*</sup>](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/76969?result=1#eid)), mas não é perfeita porque parece indicar (literalmente) movimentos respiratórios repetidos (*gasp* refere-se mais frequentemente a apenas um movimento, mas nem sempre<sup>†</sup>) e (figurativamente) agonia e não surpresa.

<sub><sup>*</sup> 1. intr. To inhale or exhale convulsively with an open mouth, as a result of distress, exertion, surprise, etc. Also fig.</sub>
<sub><sup>†</sup>1813   Scott Bridal of Triermain ii. xxv. 94   Already gasping on the ground, Lie twenty of the Table Round. [exemplo do OED]</sub>

Comment: Isto já está mais próximo. Corresponde à [aceção 2 do Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gasp), enquanto eu ando à procura da aceção 1. Curioso que não tenhas nunca encontrado *gasp*. Sendo quatro vezes menos frequente que *sigh* no [Ngram books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gasp%2Fsigh&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28gasp%20/%20sigh%29%3B%2Cc0) não é assim tão rara.

Comment: @Jacinto «esta» refere-se a «boquear», não a «gasp».

Comment: Se não há, não há. Mas *boquear* é o que fica lá mais perto.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei de nenhuma palavra que indique um som de espanto feito enquanto se inspira ar. *Arfar*, *ofegar* não se referem especificamente ao ato de inspirar e ademais indicam tendencialmente cansaço e não surpresa. E a reação de surpresa prototípica é «ficar de boca aberta».

Para as frases que dás sugiro:

> Ela **perdeu o ar** quando deu conta que já estava uma hora atrasada para a reunião.
>   Os trabalhadores **quedaram-se sufocados de espanto** quando inesperadamente ele anunciou que a empresa ia encerrar.

Comment: «Quedaram-se sufocados de espanto» (eu imaginei choque) é uma descrição alternativa da cena. Mas a frase é «Ouviu-se ...» e eu quero mesmo um equivalente a *gasp*. Para descrição alternativa mais próxima eu iria talvez por *cortou-se-lhe(s) a respiração quando...*.

Answer (score 0):

Em ptBR não temos uma única palavra que signifique exatamente "gasp".  Temos **"arquejar"**, **"arfar"**, **"inspirar"**, mas teríamos sempre que acrescentar **"subitamente"**, **"de espanto"**, **"em assombro"**, **"em horror",** etc.

> - Ao descobrir que havia sangue junto ao sofá, ela **"puxou o ar em assombro."**
> - Quando descobriu o cadáver escondido no armário, ele **"respirou fundo em horror."**

Comment: Até pensei que pudesse haver um termo médico. Ao que parece, nalguns casos as pessoas *gaspam* quando estão à beira de um ataque de coração. De qualquer modo eu procuro um equivalente de *gasp* mesmo. Para dizer uma coisa aproximada, *cortar-se-lhe a respiração (quando descobriu...)* parece-me melhor que *inspirar/ puxar ar/respirar fundo de assombro, etc.*

Comment: @Jacinto  O termo médico "respiração agônica". é genérico e refere-se a raras tentativas inspiratórias irregulares, de maior ou menor amplitude.